# Can I have multiple rows of tabs in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm wondering if it's possible to setup SQL Server to have multiple rows of tabs for files / queries.

I have a lot of queries I want to switch between, and could move them to different horizontal groups, but I think two rows would be much easier to navigate than that pin on the left that drops down the big list of open queries.

Visual Studio kind of supports this if you pin enough code windows to fill up the top bar.

Is there something similar in SQL Server?

Edit:

I'm trying to achieve something like this (screenshot from Visual Studio)

[image: Multiple Tabs]

While SQL Server is more like this

[image: Management Studio]

Comment: No, to my knowledge, there's no setting to get this, nor do I know of an extension for Mgmt Studio that would give you this feature, sorry.

Comment: @marc_s Ok, thanks. I guessed there wasn't but just wanted to check in case there was some hidden feature

Comment: This was raised twice in Microsoft Connect and was closed both times without any road map

Comment: How'd you get that to even work in Visual Studio?

Comment: @as9876 Since this post I've been using Tabs Studio. Without the addon in Visual Studio you just open new tabs until the top bar fills, then adds a second bar, or it used to. I find Tabs Studio is worth the one time investment if you spend time with VS

Comment: In other news, this feature was just [added natively to VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_53#_wrap-tabs).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I know of at least one plugin that will do this in SSMS (and Visual Studio). Because, yeah, it would be nice.

[Tabs Studio - document tabs manager for Visual Studio IDE.](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/EBF6137E-AA2D-4DC9-860A-F04168F11CD7)

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, +100!

Comment: Would be better if they sold a cheaper SSMS version - I already use a FREE plugin for VS.

Answer (score 87):

It's now available in current ssms version. From menu => Tools => options:
[image]

Comment: Yes but it only works for pinned tabs, and the pinned tabs still stay on one row of their own, no matter how many you pin. So this is not a good answer.

Comment: just pin the tabs that you always want to see

Comment: @Paul-SebastianManole I think that given the tool's lack of features, this is a great answer. Together with the other top-voted answer, it will make the experience a little more bearable :)

Answer (score 79):

By default SSMS includes Database name, File name, Login name and server name in each query tab title. So that we can see only 3 or 4 tabs at a time.

There is a work around for this, 
go to `Tools > Options > Text Editor > Editor Tab and Status Bar` and change all of the `"Tab Text"` group options to `false` except for the file name.

[image]

This will reduce the tab name, so that SSMS will show more tabs at a time

[image]

Comment: A very practical solution. I like it.

Answer (score 15):

You can do this by pinning *all* the tabs. If tabs are pinned, they won't go out of sight but will go to the next tabline instead.

The last line in the picture is a result of "Show pinned tabs in a separate row" option described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42521456/11035142).

[image]

Comment: That's actually a very neat hack!

Answer (score 10):

You can pin all tabs. Pinned tabs won't be hidden. 
[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can get a list of open tabs (Active Files) using the Ctrl-Tab shortcut. Continue pressing Tab to cycle through the list and release when the desired tab is highlighted. Or just mouse click on the required tab while keeping Ctrl depressed.

Some people do this by managing their files in an SSMS Solution and keeping the Solution Explorer loaded, but I find these to be inflexible and unwieldy.

SQL Prompt 6 has an "Open Tabs" list in the Tab History feature, which you might also find useful.