# SQL Server 2018 Management Studio - Wrap on screen all open query windows

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server Management Studio 2018 is there a way I can wrap all open queries on screen?

For example, if I have 10 open queries I want them all be wrap showing the bar on screen so I can see how many I have instead of having to click on the small arrow on the top right to see all the open queries?

So the ones that cannot be display on the right end, they would be piled up or down and I would see and have control of all the open queries?

Thank you.

Comment: This *might* be a feature in SSMS 2018, however, the latest release of [SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms) is 17.8.1. It's not a feature in that though, or not one that I am aware of.

Comment: You mean *wrap the window tabs* not the queries. That's already available for pinned tabs. Check `Tools > Options > Environment > Tabs and Windows`. Check the `Show pinned tabs in a separate row` option

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I have multiple rows of tabs in SQL Server Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22933089/can-i-have-multiple-rows-of-tabs-in-sql-server-management-studio)

Comment: Unfortunately the "show pin button in unpinned tabs just work for pinned tabs. Unpin tabs still does not work.